# if then statement, VBA, loop

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish is Excel.

Food Group    /       Food
              /   Apple
              /   Banana
              /   Carrot
              /   Broccoli

I am writing an If Then Statement to try and match Foods with their Groups.

(I know Access would be easier, but I don't want to have to keep copying and pasting from Excel to Access and back. It will only be 6 different items)

The If Then coding I made worked for just doing the first cell. But my loop is not working. Please help

```
Sub InsertFoodGroup()

    Dim food As String, group As String
    Dim i As Integer

    i = Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown).Row

    food = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(i, 2)).Value

        Do While Cells(i, 2).Value <> ""
            If food = "Apple" Then
                group = "Fruit"
            ElseIf food = "Banana" Then
                group = "Fruit"
            ElseIf food = "Carrot" Then
                group = "Vegetable"
            ElseIf food = "Broccoli" Then
                group = "Vegetable"
            Else
                total = "false"
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop

    Range(Cells(2, 21), Cells(i, 21)).Value = group

End Sub
```

Comment: You forgot to set the value of the food variable in your code.

Comment: When you say **not working** what exactly is not working?

Comment: Well, 1) `i` starts already from the end of the data, you probably want to say `i = 2` and `Do While Cells(i,2).Value <> ""`; 2) `food` has no value assigned; 3) `group` is assigned everytime but not used anywhere; 4) if you want to match the `food` with the `group`, you probably want to return `group`, not `total`, and you want to do it before every `Loop`.

Comment: Sorry. I changed the names from my actual sheet and forgot to change them all. I edited the code and gave the food and group ranges

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest the use of a very simple UDF:

```
Public Function foodToGroup(ByVal food As String) As Variant
    Select Case food
        Case "Apple", "Banana":
        foodToGroup = "Fruit"
        Case "Carrot", "Broccoli":
        foodToGroup = "Vegetable"
        Case Else
        foodToGroup = False
    End Select
End Function
```

Hence, assuming your data are in "A1:A100", you will only need to type `=foodToGroup(A1)` in cell "B1" (or wherever you need to) and then drag the function down until the end of your data.

Please note that this might be easily reached through a simple Excel formula: `=IF(OR(A1="Banana",A1="Apple"),"Fruit",IF(OR(A1="Carrot",A1="Broccoli"),"Vegetable",FALSE))`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is a file that has about 3,000 lines done monthly by different people. I was trying to simplify the process to make it as user friendly as possible.

Again, thank you :)

Comment: @emilyj914 you mean that the above solution doesnt work? Can i help you to fix it?